# Error in launching TensorBoard

Tags: tensorboard

I have installed TensorBoard. Before launching, I have also written the code in my neural network training file.

```
sess = tf.Session()  
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("demo")
writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```

When i try to launch TensorBoard from terminal, using this command `tensorboard --logdir=logs/` 
I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/tensorboard", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorboard.main import run_main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorboard import default
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorboard/default.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.audio import audio_plugin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorboard/plugins/audio/audio_plugin.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.audio import metadata
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorboard/plugins/audio/metadata.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.audio import plugin_data_pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorboard/plugins/audio/plugin_data_pb2.py", line 22, in <module>
    serialized_pb=_b('\n+tensorboard/plugins/audio/plugin_data.proto\x12\x0btensorboard\"}\n\x0f\x41udioPluginData\x12\x0f\n\x07version\x18\x01 \x01(\x05\x12\x37\n\x08\x65ncoding\x18\x02 \x01(\x0e\x32%.tensorboard.AudioPluginData.Encoding\" \n\x08\x45ncoding\x12\x0b\n\x07UNKNOWN\x10\x00\x12\x07\n\x03WAV\x10\x0b\x62\x06proto3')
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options'
```

Is there a problem in my audio plugin or in the installation? I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I am a beginner, pardon if i have overlooked anything basic.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on windows. I removed protobuf and libprotobuf and then reinstalled tensorboard, and it worked!

Not sure why, but while trying to find a solution like you it seemed like protobuf caused such issues in other libraries so I tried